# Rotate UIButton titleLabel without clipping

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uibutton, facebook-pop

I'm trying to rotate the titleLabel of a UIButton by 45 degrees. The character in the text is '+'.

I can get the title to rotate with

`button.titleLabel?.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(CGFloat(M_PI_4))`

But then one end of the '+' symbol is clipped, as in the following screenshots.

[image]
[image]

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17476142/uibuttons-titlelabel-clips-text-after-being-rotated-by-cgaffinetransformmakerota), but I couldn't quite follow how the problem was fixed. It's strange that the clipped section still exists within the bounds of the other ends—it doesn't protrude outside the 'square' of the symbol.

I also tried to use Facebook's Pop library, which kind of worked, except I couldn't work out how to do a normal anti-clockwise or clockwise rotation. I used `kPOPLayerRotation` with `M_PI_4` and it did something unexpected. I'm happy to use Pop if someone can provide sample code for basic clockwise/anticlockwise rotation.

A possibly related issue: the centre of the titleLabel moves as well. Is there an easy way to prevent this?

Thanks very much for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone coming to this in the future, I ended up creating a new UIView (the blue rectangle) which contained the UIButton (the white '+'). I then disabled used interaction on the UIButton, and added a gesture recogniser to the UIView. When I wanted to rotate the '+', I rotated the whole UIButton (but not the containing UIView).

Answer (score 1):

You are rotating the button's titleLabel, which is inside of the button. Button wasn't rotated. but label was rotated. So You are getting the clip or center misalignment of label. I suggest you to rotate the button itself. So it will rotate its subviews as well.

```
// Check already it was rotated,transformed...?
if (CGAffineTransformIsIdentity(button.transform)) {

    //Yes, Reset to the original position and size.
    button.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;

}

//Apply rotation now
button.transform=CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI_4);
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. After that, how do I reset the frame of the button so that only the titleLabel has rotated, and not the whole button? I tried doing `button.bounds = CGRectMake(...)` but that didn't fix it.

Comment: just use  button.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity; then setframe of the button.

Comment: I tried to do something like `button.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(CGFloat(M_PI_4))` then `button.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity` and then `button.frame = CGRectMake(...)`, however this had no effect (i.e. whole button would rotate, then rotate back, but the actual title of the button would be back where it started—a regular '+').